# How to get data out of backgrid js and submit it in a form submit?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, backgrid

How to extract JSON data that I've already displayed in a grid using backgridjs, to submit via form post submit?

Answer (score 0):

`collection.toJSON()` will return all the data in a hash. You can turn it into form encoded key values pairs and submit that via Ajax. jQuery and Underscore has all the methods you need to achieve that.